# How to get a document library folder url using PowerAutomate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have an app I need to get the url of folders from a SharePint document library.
and update my dataverse table url column with the link.

How can I get the url of a folder from SharePoint document library through power automate, the folders are dynamically generated through power automate so I need to get the folder url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Get files (properties only)" action to list all files and folders in a Document Library. You can also filter to only return folders with Filter query: `FSObjType eq 1`.

For example:

[image]